# Verify elements are ordered alphabetically or by specific parameter

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Let's say there are three dropdowns on this page http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown

Dropdown 1
Dropdown A
Dropdown B

In the first dropdown items are in alphabetical order. In the second dropdown items are in reverse-alphabetical order. In the third dropdown items are ordered by the text length asc.

How to verify dropdowns vertical (or horizontal) order and items order in each dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

Get the values in the order that they appear, perhaps using [Get Text](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Text) with the xpath of each item. Then, to see if they are sorted, make a copy of the list and sort the copy. Then simply compare the sorted list to the original.

Comment: Thank you ! For few dropdowns, does it make sense to use Get Horizontal (or vertical) position and then compare elements positions with each other ?